# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

`Solution Tried :`

**1. Upgraded Okhttp library's version**
**2. Downgraded OkHttp library's version**

**in both scenario app was crashing so now version is set to 4.9.0 and now app is not getting crashed but issue is that api is not getting called.**

Comment: Please provide some context - stack trace and what triggers the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was fixed a long time ago.  Upgrading to 4.9.1 should make it go away.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/edf477cb4e7b1d59c6e3e5ac00870619340ce990/docs/changelog_3x.md#version-3147

But you haven't provided any detail to fix the other issue.